# How use vue datepicker in nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I trying to use the vue-datepicker (https://vue3datepicker.com/installation/) with no success
First I create one class on my \plugins directory: ('\plugins\vue-datepicker.js')

```
import Datepicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker';
  
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(Datepicker)
})
```

then I try to use in my app

```
<Datepicker />
```

but I got this erro:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: DatePicker
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
```

Comment: Does it work with a local import: https://vue3datepicker.com/installation/#local ?

Comment: @kissu works but I got some warning 'No match found for location with path "/main.css.map"'

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if correct or not, but it works for me

`plugins/vuedatepicker.js`

```js
import VueDatePicker from "@vuepic/vue-datepicker";
import "@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component("vue-date-picker", VueDatePicker);
});
```

`index.uve`

```js
<template>
  ...
  <vue-date-picker v-model="value"></vue-date-picker>
  ...
</template>
```

or [Local](https://vue3datepicker.com/installation/#local)

`nuxt.config.ts`

ref: https://vue3datepicker.com/installation/#nuxt

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  build: {
    transpile: ["@vuepic/vue-datepicker"],
  },
});
```

`index.vue`

```js
<template>
  <vue-date-picker v-model="currentValue"></vue-date-picker>
</template>

<script>
import VueDatePicker from "@vuepic/vue-datepicker";
import "@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css";

export default {
  ...
  components: {
    VueDatePicker,
  },
  ...
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
yarn add @vuepic/vue-datepicker
```

## or

```
npm install @vuepic/vue-datepicker
```

You should import from this url

```
import VueDatePicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker';
import '@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css';
```

And you can use like this example:

```
<VueDatePicker v-model="date" placeholder="Choose the date" />
```

The components should be same : **VueDatePicker**

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make it global in nuxt3 and get all typescript hints currectlly using your code editor (props suggestions - props types - methods - evenets & ...) simplye create a component file in nuxt "**components**" directory called **"VueDatePicker.vue"** (or what ever you want)
then inside VueDatePicker.vue:

```
<script lang="ts">
import VueDatePicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker'
import '@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css'
export default VueDatePicker
</script>
```

now you can use it globally in all pages and components (with all typescript hits)